# select2 not showing properly as shown in select2 example page

Tags: jquery-select2

I m using select2 with Laravel Blade engine and i use it for [loading remote data](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) and its work fine (getting data from remote) but its not look like select2 box. i also attach image for my resulting select2.

My CSS file include in  section as follows

```
     {{--Bootstrap--}}
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('css/plugin/font-awesome.min.css') }}
    {{--select2--}}
{{ HTML::style('css/plugin/select2/select2.min.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('css/plugin/select2/select2-bootstrap.css') }}
```

My Js file include as follows after body tag

```
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.min.js') }}

{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}

{{ HTML::script('js/plugin/select2/select2.min.js') }}

{{ HTML::script('js/plugin/select2/select2.js') }}
```

MY HTML code

```
<input type="hidden"  id="student-name-search"
 data-placeholder="Select Student" value="" data-option="" style="width:100%">  </input>
```

Image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SDyt.png)

Comment: Can you post your js script as well and html code. Your input here is hidden so i think you have more

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a select input in your HTML like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});

<select class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am using old version of select2 and in that version <input type="hidden"> works. and its also work here fine.. but shown 2 text boxes...